# Query data via username - pair - best performance

Tags: query-performance, optimization, mariadb, performance-tuning

RDBMS: MariaDB 10.3

Let's say you have a table which stores specific information (`info_1`, `info_2`, etc.) according to a given pair of usernames; like so:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+--..
|  user_1  |  user_2  |  info_1  |  info_2  |  info_3  |  ..  |  ..
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+--..
```

where the values of `user_1` and `user_2` each equal a specific & distinct username (`VARCHAR(50)`), and are defined as multi-column index (user_1,user_2) of the table upon creation.
The queries my app does search in function of:

A) a given user pair:

`WHERE user_1 = name_1 AND user_2 = name_2 OR user_1 = name_2 AND user_2 = name_1`

B) a given user / return all the records where a specific user is one of the members:

`WHERE user_1 = name_1 OR user_1 = '%' AND user_2 = name_1`

Problem: I must make sure that searches are always indexed. When using an `OR` clause, a full table scan is however executed each time.

**SOLUTION I)**

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65050279/single-vs-multi-column-index-for-optimized-database-performance) answer, possible queries resulting in indexed searches for these cases is:

A)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_1 = name_1 AND user_2 = name_2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_1 = name_2 AND user_2 = name_1;
```

B)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_1 = name_1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_1 = '%' AND user_2 = name_1;
```

However with the drawback of always using two `SELECT` statements and one `WHERE` clause which will always be in vain (as there will always be one record per user-pair). That's why I attempted to further optimize the query by using a [fulltext index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-index-overview/), which resulted in the following table:

**SOLUTION II)**

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+------+--..
|  users  |  info_1  |  info_2  |  info_3  |  ..  |  ..
+---------+----------+----------+----------+------+--..
```

where `users` has been defined as `FULLTEXT VARCHAR(150)`, and its value always corresponds to the format `name_1-name_2`, whereas I used a hyphen because a comma is used in the `MATCH...AGAINST` syntax to execute fulltext index queries.

With this structure, I now get the following new query possibilities for A) and B):

A)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(users) AGAINST ('"name_1-name_2","name_2-name_1"');
```

B)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(users) AGAINST ('name_1');
```

Which in my opinion drastically facilitate the query structure, and use neither two `SELECT` statements, nor an additional `WHERE` clause which will be in vain. Still, as I don't know a lot yet about query performance optimization and the comparison of fulltext index searches with regular index searches, I wondered which solution of I and II may perform better, and why ? Or is there even a better approach?

Comment: as long there is only the fulltext index and you get the wanted results, it is good, but in cobination with other where conditions it woll get slow, but you should take a look at elastic search, for text searching

Comment: You mean the third-party software by "elastic search", or some built-in feature of mariaDB (that I can't find..)? The fulltext index is all I want to query for, maybe add one or two additional features of the records returned by the fulltext index search (which will be max. 10 records, so I guess that's fine if I postpone another condition with ```AND``` afterwards?). Also, in generall you then agree that solution II, using fulltext indexes, instead of solution I using two selects and a union, will perform better?

Comment: if we are spreaking of 2 million rows, you will noticed a difference. with smal databases a fulltext index, will use to much space. the thridparty tools elastic search is used for big tables and text search, as you seem to do a bit of research you should takle a look as i suggested. my warning was when yu search for the names with fullztext and another inbdexed column and use AND in the WJERE clause, this gets slow.

Comment: Okay, so you suggest that I better start off with solution I (to begin I mean; I'll also have a look at elastic search in the meantime)?

Comment: yes the UNION should be enough, and when the database grows, look at the Fulltext index, which has also drw backs, and elastic search for big tables, when you have data rin the qieries and look

Comment: so (to understand you correctly), the UNION solution performs better than the one with the fulltext index?? I'd be glad if you could explain why, or provide me with an explanatory link / tutorial, I'd really like to understand these things properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Critique**

1A cannot use indexes because of `OR`

1B -- `user_1 = '%'` prevents the use of `INDEX(user_1, ...)`, so solution 1B is out.

1B can be salvaged by having a second index:  `INDEX(user_2)`.  Then simply say

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_1 = name_1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_2 = name_1;
```

2-- FULLTEXT has limitations, such as "word" length.  So be cautious.

2A  (`WHERE MATCH(users) AGAINST ('"name_1-name_2","name_2-name_1"')` -- it is probably sufficient to say simply
`WHERE MATCH(users) AGAINST ('+name_1 +name_2' IN BOOLEAN MODE); The` +` says that both are required, but in any order.

2B -- OK (with the above caveats)

`FULLTEXT`, *when it is applicable*, is likely to be *very* performant.  Here are two tricks I have used:

```
WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST("R +James" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The short 'word' (R) will be ignored; it will search for James efficiently.  Note the selective use of '+'.

```
WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST("R +Anders" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND user LIKE "%R. Anders%"
```

This assumes that the name might be in the middle of a large column, and I need to check the initial.  The FT test will be first (and fast), followed by the LIKE (slow, but against few rows).

That still has problems because of "E. Anders and R. Anderson" would be wrongly caught.

(Etc, etc.  But I digress from your simple 2-word use case.)

**Bottom line:**

1B (extra index) is optimal.  (But I suspect you watered down the Question.)

`FULLTEXT` would be my next choice.

**Let me add an option 3:**

Sort the users before inserting and when querying.  That is

```
INSERT ... (user1, user2)
   VALUES
   (LEAST(?, ?), GREATEST(?, ?))
```

then you need (for case A) only `INDEX(user1, user2)` together with

```
WHERE user1 = LEAST(?, ?)
  AND user1 = GREATEST(?, ?)
```

Alas, that will probably mess up case B.  (Do *all* rows have 2 user names, but *some* queries have only 1 user?)

**And Option 4**

Have another table that maps user names to `my_table` by `id`.  Typically 2 rows in this new table for each row in `my_table`.  Optionally toss the user columns from `my_table`.

I won't go into the rest of the detail; they do get messy.

Comment: All rows have 2 usernames. The query in style B) is used to return all the records where a specific username is one of the users.
Thanks for the proposition in 2A, I'll stick to that (added the "+", but forgot the "IN BOOLEAN MODE", now I get it..). 
As for the length min (4) and max (84), there's no need to worry, given that usernames all have fixed lengths and the format / length is thus always exactly the same. So no need to worry for that in my case. What is your opinion on the comments above, e.g. that ```WHERE MATCH(users) AGAINST(name) AND info_1 = X``` will slow down the query??

Comment: Actually, there is a big problem, and I cannot even use full text index searches. The reson is that I use queries which ```JOIN``` based on the value of a username column, via ```INNER JOIN ON MATCH(users) AGAINST(username_column)```, but it is actually not possible to provide a column name to the ```AGAINST``` function. So sad. Guess I'll have to stick to the ```UNION``` solutions 1A and 1B anyway, and use all the primary key on ID, the multi-column index on user_1 and user_2, and the single index on user_2, as you said. Just seems weird to me to use a multi-column and single index on user_2.

Comment: @DevelJoe - `MATCH... AND ...` will quickly do the `MATCH`, _then_ it will quickly toss out some of those rows based on the `AND`.  Not a problem.  `OR` would be a big performance problem.

Comment: @DevelJoe - `INDEX(u1, u2)` handles _both_ parts of 1A.  It fails when `u1` is not tested with `=`.  So `INDEX(u2)` is needed only for `WHERE u2='xx'` without `u1`.

Comment: Yep got that! Ok cheers, now I'm needing to make all the concerned queries with inner joins and this table index-based, shall I update the question above or start a new one? It's all bout the same tables.. Thx already buddy!

Comment: @DevelJoe - A `JOIN` could involve needing an index that involves two table, which is not possible.  In that case it is a totally different Question.  Play it safe, start a new Question.  At worst, that may become a "dup" of this.

Comment: Guess I found a solution which uses a CTE and the exact same three indexes we discussed here, so it seems like it's all working; otherwise you'll see a new question popup after our testings haha! Thank you so much man, greatly appreciated!

Comment: @DevelJoe - You could post your CTE as another Answer.  (Answering one's own Question is allowed.)

Comment: I meant that the CTE is rather a solution for the inner join thing, so nothing rly to do with this :)